# Want output in 2 digit before and after decimal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cpu, kali-linux-tools

```bash
#!/bin/bash
CPU=$(top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" |  sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | bc -l ) 
USES=$(echo "100 - $CPU"|bc -l) 
FINAL="$USES% CPU"
echo "$FINAL"
```

This was a script I wrote for calculating my CPU usage, it gives what it was meant to offer but when I run this command in 'kargos' a KDE widget displays the output of a command as a widget. Every time its output changes from 1.2% to 11.4% it causes all other widgets to move because that one digit is now added to the LHS of the decimal.
So, I wanted even if my CPU utilization is 2.4% it should give output as 02.4% and if CPU utilization is 11.4% it should output as 11.4% only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the shell's builtin `printf` function rather than `echo` if you want control over output formating:

```
printf '%04.1f%% CPU\n' "$USES"
```

Ex.

```
$ printf '%04.1f%% CPU\n' 11
11.0% CPU

$ printf '%04.1f%% CPU\n' 9
09.0% CPU
```

As an aside, it's recommended to avaoid `ALLCAPS` for your own shell variable names - they're informally reserved for system variables.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I guess from now onwards I will be formatting my text output using print.